# Theano and tensorflow conv2D produce different outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

Below code is written in theano and produces some output

```
import theano
import tensorflow as tf
from theano import tensor as T
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv2d

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
wt_th = np.random.uniform(low=-0.5, high=0.5, size=(16,3,5,5)).astype(np.float32)

np.random.seed(1)
inp = np.random.rand(128,3,128,128).astype(np.float32)

np.random.seed(1)
bias = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(16)).astype(np.float32)

# instantiate 4D tensor for input
input = T.tensor4(name='input')

# initialize shared variable for weights.
w_shp = (16, 3, 5, 5)
W = theano.shared(wt_th , name ='W')

b_shp = (16,)
b = theano.shared(bias, name ='b')

# build symbolic expression that computes the convolution of input with filters in w
conv_out = conv2d(input, W)

output = T.nnet.relu(conv_out + b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))

# create theano function to compute filtered images
f = theano.function([input], output)
res = f(inp)
print res[0][0][0]
```

[2.8236432 2.094213  1.4916432 3.525494  2.3700824 1.8851945 2.2574215
 3.3974087 1.9719648 1.3346338 0.7322583 1.4527869 2.9211016 2.4242344
 2.6613848 3.1885512 2.8935843 3.7721367 1.0875871 1.8844371 3.6890957
 2.1210446 3.4621592 2.2298138 2.1788187 3.1571674 2.080009  1.4983883
 3.3549118 1.8853223 2.0242834 2.8072758 4.2562714 3.6012995 2.2535224
 3.87668   3.3886926 3.697033  3.3373523 2.2016246 3.5874677 3.0154514
 2.434566  3.6492867 2.2965183 2.6377907 2.2562    2.8330164 2.1103406
 2.9778543 2.3738375 3.1129453 1.277472  1.1789091 2.4199317 2.619667
 2.5976152 1.0020001 2.562955  1.6254797 1.9258347 1.5564928 3.5225492
 3.1682463 2.179951  3.2768161 2.2703805 2.0199404 2.4948874 2.9022932
 3.0263028 2.264034  1.9042997 1.6110027 3.6300693 1.899374  2.9140353
 2.8552768 2.7125297 2.7972744 2.0619967 3.8458047 3.140479  1.6845248
 3.844461  3.8562043 2.5270283 2.4488764 2.7029114 1.8886952 3.034019
 3.1078124 1.9806297 4.573     2.769538  2.6645966 3.501518  2.2144883
 1.8297508 3.3294327 2.7242799 2.187298  2.5060043 1.9938259 3.914175
 3.7276266 2.6536622 2.896241  2.821738  1.592206  1.8782039 2.648998
 2.284129  3.4120197 2.6911411 3.2339904 2.5738459 2.8637185 1.8006318
 3.1124763 2.1838622 2.6475391 1.7801914 2.5641136]

W is of the format ( num_output_channel,num_input_channel,height,widht )

input is of the format(batch_size, num_channels, height, width)

Now I have written a function to convert the weights from theano format to tensorflow format and also change the input shape to tf format 
but the below code produces different output than the one above

```
def convert_filter(wts):
    wts = np.moveaxis(wts, 0, 3)
    wts = np.moveaxis(wts, 0, 2)
    return wts

def convert_input(inp):
    inp = np.moveaxis(inp,1,3)
    return inp

input_shape = [128,128, 3]

X = tf.placeholder(shape = [None] + input_shape, dtype=tf.float32, name='X')

wt_tf = convert_filter(wt_th).astype(np.float32)

conv_kernel_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, wt_tf, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID',use_cudnn_on_gpu=False)

bias_layer_1 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_kernel_1, bias)

act_out = tf.nn.relu(bias_layer_1)

inp_tf = convert_input(inp)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(act_out, feed_dict={X:inp_tf})
    out = np.moveaxis(out, 3, 1)
print out[0][0][0]
```

[ 2.67197418  2.15853548  2.06719136  3.01160574  3.22447252  3.077492
  2.52125549  3.08207083  2.29633474  1.86849833  2.03281307  2.28387547
  2.67936897  2.48002243  2.31078005  3.56169009  3.12560081  2.61774731
  1.82814527  3.23375154  3.25905514  2.39252329  3.13444471  2.00132608
  2.41169739  1.86714172  3.01640558  2.51328039  2.07797813  1.77424145
  1.8954494   2.98585939  2.98480368  2.57455826  2.36318088  3.88532543
  2.38877392  2.86067486  2.78855133  2.63732243  2.63163185  2.79659152
  1.98354578  2.77975321  2.12787509  2.71589994  3.44908381  2.02305984
  3.04079533  2.60647154  2.14657426  2.74537277  3.07799053  2.49051762
  4.77739191  3.12529612  2.30980444  2.31344223  2.02293968  3.04298592
  3.4453795   3.58379078  3.32912683  3.26278138  1.48381591  2.32841253
  1.97166562  3.04377413  3.12559581  2.27840328  2.93908429  0.96808767
  3.17380023  1.60673594  2.59704685  3.98458505  1.25713849  1.90271974
  1.82997131  2.93574715  2.14195251  3.26882362  2.09072447  2.07539392
  3.77434778  1.82215333  3.30864692  1.52123737  2.29328823  1.36722493
  3.34969425  2.55285358  3.15811181  4.44630671  2.7549541   2.83824682
  2.50485158  2.45610046  1.5423398   3.12460995  2.38987827  0.983325
  2.64392757  3.11031628  1.41283321  2.58364391  2.17403984  3.19049454
  2.83069992  1.04926252  2.93791962  2.37773943  3.51300693  3.02249169
  2.59249544  1.81437802  3.34520817  3.04475498  4.02190208  3.84745455
  2.45946741  2.06334138  2.11823249  2.95765638]

Why the outputs are different ?

Comment: Did you run this on the GPU or CPU in tensorflow?

Comment: It is resolved. The error was due to convolution and cross-corelation

Comment: Good to hear, you should answer the question yourself (for the benefit of others) or delete it then.